# libvirtd: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libvirt.so.0: undefined symbol: ssh_get_publickey

Tags: fedora, libvirt

I have a lite problem with libvirtd . I do not use kvm by few mouth and after upgrade from fedora 25 to 26 . Re-installation all packages libvirt does not help

```
#libvirtd -d                                                                                                                      
libvirtd: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libvirt.so.0: undefined symbol: ssh_get_publickey
```

journal logs from starting service

> Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz libvirtd[5670]: /usr/sbin/libvirtd: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libvirt.so.0: undefined symbol: ssh_get_publickey
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=libvirtd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit entered failed state.
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=libvirtd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=libvirtd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon.
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
>   Oct 15 13:30:22 Euzebiusz libvirtd[5671]: /usr/sbin/libvirtd: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libvirt.so.0: undefined symbol: ssh_get_publickey
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=libvirtd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit entered failed state.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=libvirtd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'                                                    Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=libvirtd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'                                                     Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz libvirtd[5672]: /usr/sbin/libvirtd: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libvirt.so.0: undefined symbol: ssh_get_publickey
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=libvirtd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'                                                     Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit entered failed state.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=libvirtd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=libvirtd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit entered failed state.
>   Oct 15 13:30:23 Euzebiusz systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

additional vesrsion libvirt.so

```
dnf whatprovides '*/libvirt.so.0'
Last metadata expiration check: 2:07:45 ago on Sun 15 Oct 2017 11:47:59 AM CEST.                                                              
libvirt-libs-3.2.1-6.fc26.x86_64 : Client side libraries               
Repo        : @System                                                  
Matched from:                                                          
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libvirt.so.0                                  

libvirt-libs-3.2.1-6.fc26.i686 : Client side libraries                 
Repo        : updates                                                  
Matched from:                                                          
Filename    : /usr/lib/libvirt.so.0                                    

libvirt-libs-3.2.1-6.fc26.x86_64 : Client side libraries               
Repo        : updates                                                  
Matched from:                                                          
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libvirt.so.0                                  

libvirt-libs-3.2.1-3.fc26.i686 : Client side libraries                 
Repo        : fedora                                                   
Matched from:                                                          
Filename    : /usr/lib/libvirt.so.0                                    

libvirt-libs-3.2.1-3.fc26.x86_64 : Client side libraries               
Repo        : fedora                                                   
Matched from:                                                          
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libvirt.so.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked libs again and install additional x86 lib

```
dnf install libvirt-libs-3.2.1-6.fc26.i686
```

after  install i686 package work correctly

```
dnf whatprovides '*/libvirt.so.0'
Last metadata expiration check: 2:07:45 ago on Sun 15 Oct 2017 11:47:59 AM CEST.                                                              
libvirt-libs-3.2.1-6.fc26.x86_64 : Client side libraries               
Repo        : @System                                                  
Matched from:                                                          
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libvirt.so.0                                  

libvirt-libs-3.2.1-6.fc26.i686 : Client side libraries                 
Repo        : @System                                                  
Matched from:                                                          
Filename    : /usr/lib/libvirt.so.0
```